# Excel or R: reshaping data

Tags: r, excel, data-manipulation

I have some data that looks like:

```
ID Data

1  a b c 
2  a b c a b c
3  a b c 
4  a b c a b c a b c a b c
5  a b c a b c a b c
```

I would like it in the following

```
ID Data

1 a b c
2 a b c
2 a b c
3 a b c
4 a b c
4 a b c
4 a b c
4 a b c
5 a b c
5 a b c
5 a b c
```

`a`, `b` and `c` are in different column cells so `Data` is actually many columns. I can concatenate them if need be.

Essentially `a` `b` and `c` are related but for some IDs I have multiple results and I'd like the data in a long format rather than wide but keeping the ID for each row.

I can do in this is R if that's easier too.

Dput:

```
structure(list(ID = c(9999812L, 999908L, 9993595L, 9992905L, 
9989664L, 9984487L, 9980956L, 9980112L, 9980091L, 9979915L, 9979613L, 
9979400L, 9978215L, 9976882L, 9975335L, 9974511L, 9973804L, 9973025L
), a = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "a", class = "factor"), 
    b = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "b", class = "factor"), 
    c = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "c", class = "factor"), 
    a.1 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("", "a"), class = "factor"), 
    b.1 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("", "b"), class = "factor"), 
    c.1 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("", "c"), class = "factor"), 
    a.2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("", "a"), class = "factor"), 
    b.2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("", "b"), class = "factor"), 
    c.2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("", "c"), class = "factor"), 
    a.3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("", "a"), class = "factor"), 
    b.3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("", "b"), class = "factor"), 
    c.3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("", "c"), class = "factor"), 
    a.4 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("", "a"), class = "factor"), 
    b.4 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("", "b"), class = "factor"), 
    c.4 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("", "c"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", 
"a", "b", "c", "a.1", "b.1", "c.1", "a.2", "b.2", "c.2", "a.3", 
"b.3", "c.3", "a.4", "b.4", "c.4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))
```

Comment: Are there column headings? (ie. is `a` always "First name" for example? are there only these three data types or are there columns `d` etc that you just want to ignore?

Comment: If 'a', 'b', 'c' are in different columns, then you will have different column names for it.

Comment: you have a unique id for each row.

Comment: I can make heading but the lengths are unequal and I wouldnt want rows with an ID followed by blank cells. ID in the first table is unqiue. It wont be when transformed so it accounts for rows in the firs with multiple a,b and c's

Comment: Imagine a is car manufacturer, b is model and c is engine size and for some IDs we have more than one car. Does that help?

Comment: Can you use `dput` to make your example reproducible please?

Comment: How do you want your output? (based on your example)

Comment: dput added. Id like it like the second table where we only have 4 columns but ID's are now non unique

Comment: a b and c are strings, I just cant give you the real data

Comment: I don't want the real data. Your previous `dput` was different from what you were describing, hence my output question

Comment: Yeh I was using read.table("clipboard", header=T, fill=T) and it didnt come out right before. This is more accurate but ive replaced my strings with a b and c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your initial data, you can use "stringr" and "reshape2" to melt the data.

```
dt <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = c( "a b c" , "a b c a b c","a b c","a b c a b c a b c a b c", "a b c a b c a b c"))

library("stringr")
library("reshape2")
maxlen <- max(lengths(str_extract_all(dt$y,"(\\w)\\s(\\w)\\s(\\w)(\\1\\s\\2\\s\\3)*")))

list_lists <- str_extract_all(dt$y,"(\\w)\\s(\\w)\\s(\\w)(\\1\\s\\2\\s\\3)*")

li <- lapply(list_lists, `length<-`,maxlen)

dtnew <- data.frame(x =cbind(dt$x),do.call("rbind",li))
dtnew1 <- melt(dtnew,id.vars="x")
dtnew1 <- dtnew1[!is.na(dtnew1$value),]
dtnew1[order(dtnew1$x),]

   > dtnew1[order(dtnew1$x),c(1,3)]
   x value
1  1 a b c
2  2 a b c
7  2 a b c
3  3 a b c
4  4 a b c
9  4 a b c
14 4 a b c
19 4 a b c
5  5 a b c
10 5 a b c
15 5 a b c
>
```

**EDIT**: For the updated data, make a field called "`concat`", which is concatenated value of columns "a" to "c.4"

You can use : `concat <- data.frame(concat=do.call("paste0",dt[,2:length(dt)]))` to concatenate fields

then assign `dt$concat <- concat`

```
library("stringr")
library("reshape2")

maxlen <- max(lengths(str_extract_all(dt$concat,"(\\w)(\\w)(\\w)")))

list_lists <- str_extract_all(dt$concat,"(\\w)(\\w)(\\w)")

li <- lapply(list_lists, `length<-`,maxlen)

dtnew <- data.frame(x =cbind(dt$ID),y=do.call("rbind",li))
dtnew1 <- melt(dtnew,id.vars="x")
dtnew1 <- dtnew1[!is.na(dtnew1$value),]
dtnew1[order(dtnew1$x),c(1,3)]

> dtnew1[order(dtnew1$x),c(1,3)]
         x value
2   999908   abc
18 9973025   abc
36 9973025   abc
54 9973025   abc
72 9973025   abc
90 9973025   abc
17 9973804   abc
35 9973804   abc
16 9974511   abc
15 9975335   abc
33 9975335   abc
51 9975335   abc
69 9975335   abc
14 9976882   abc
13 9978215   abc
12 9979400   abc
30 9979400   abc
48 9979400   abc
11 9979613   abc
10 9979915   abc
9  9980091   abc
8  9980112   abc
7  9980956   abc
6  9984487   abc
24 9984487   abc
5  9989664   abc
4  9992905   abc
3  9993595   abc
1  9999812   abc
19 9999812   abc
>
```

Comment: Due to the nature of my strings, can you assume each a,b or c are in different columns. I have it in a data frame with 60K rows and 43 columns (most only have data in the first 4 columns the rest are often blank)

Comment: Id guess something like after ID, concatenate each group of 3 columns, melt that, then cSplit that back out

Comment: Okay, this works with the test data, however in my data a is a string that may have spaces inetween. Will that throw \\w? I can add a , to each string at the end for delimiter

Comment: so a could be "Hello world" b could be "string" and c could be "I like turtles". They are only using letters and spaces with no special characters

Comment: if you want to match x <- c("hello world,I like turtles"), to match both the string in a same string, you can use : `str_extract_all(x,"[\\w\\s]{1,}")`, basically you have tweak the str_extract everytime if there is change in pattern , I would recommend you to use stringr and `str_view` to see the  matches in html view, this will increase your intuition on regex